# Set the last digit not zero

Tags: javascript, qualtrics

I have a entry field in qualtrics that requires people to enter a subunit that has 4 digits. How can I embed a JavaScript code that does NOT allow the last digit to be a zero into Qualtrics?

Comment: The [remainder operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Remainder) could help with this. `if(myNumber %10 ===0) { /* last number is zero */ }`. You could also use a RegExp `if(/0$/.test(myNumber)) { /* last number is zero */ }`, although RegExp isn't as reliable if your number could possibly have a decimal place, like 4224.0

Comment: this isn't really a javascript question is it?  qualtrics validation allows regex, so you can just use that